# Excel VBA Remove content from cells then delete total rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am programming to review a range, remove content from the range of cells, then delete the entire row of cells that have been cleared of content. Currently, I run the code and all the rows are getting deleted. Also, I appreciate suggestions to make the code DRY.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Alfredo()

Dim msg As String
Dim VarCase As Range
Dim ws As Worksheets

Set ws = Sheets("Data")

For Each VarCase In ws.Range("D1:D11000")
If VarCase.Value2 = "John" Or VarCase.Value2 = "Thompson" Or VarCase.Value2 = 
"Mattson" Then
VarCase.ClearContents
End If
Next VarCase

For Each VarCase In ws.Range("D1:D11000")
If VarCase.Value = "" Then
Rows.EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next VarCase

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your final For loop, you have

```
Rows.EntireRow.Delete
```

where you should have

```
VarCase.EntireRow.Delete
```

which probably accounts for the general deletion.

The For Each construct doesn't always work happily with a range that is being changed (here by row deletion), so beware that. You could potentially accumulate a Range of deletion targets via Union and delete in one statement at the end for DRYness, without any clearing of contents.

Also, indentation is your friend.

---

Edit to add illustration of Union approach:

```
Sub TestRowDelete()
Dim ARange As Range
Dim DRange As Range

Set DRange = Nothing

For Each ARange In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows
    If ARange(1).Value = "d" Then ' testing first cell on each row
        If DRange Is Nothing Then
            Set DRange = ARange
        Else
            Set DRange = Union(DRange, ARange)
        End If
    End If
Next ARange

If Not DRange Is Nothing Then DRange.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put this code under this code under the data worksheet in VBA

```
Sub Alfredo()

Dim msg As String
Dim VarCase As Range

For Each VarCase In ActiveSheet.Range("D:D")
  If VarCase.Value2 = "John" Or VarCase.Value2 = "Thompson" Or VarCase.Value2 = "Mattson" Then
   VarCase.ClearContents
  End If
Next VarCase

 For Each VarCase In ActiveSheet.Range("D:D")
   If VarCase.Value = "" Then
    VarCase.EntireRow.Delete
   End If
 Next VarCase

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why loop twice?

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim VarCase As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Data")
For Each VarCase In ws.Range("D1:D11000")

    If VarCase.Value2 = "John" Or VarCase.Value2 = "Thompson" Or VarCase.Value2 = "Mattson" Then
       VarCase.ClearContents
       VarCase.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

Next VarCase
```

Comment: Hi Tony, I can't the code to execute, the excel wheel just spins for over 10 minutes